# Can i use a different parser for Axis 1.4?

Tags: java, web-services, axis, xstream, xerces

The current SAX parser takes a lot of time (20 minutes) and heap memory(around 400mb) to deserialize the response coming from the soap server as per the logs. Our response XMLs are of average size 4 mb.

A part of the log when it runs the applicaiton out of heap is below

```
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Pushing handler org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHandler@16d22f1
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle) org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(newElem00)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement) New MessageElement (org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement@112c22) named {}name
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Pushing element name
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.utils.NSStack) NSPush (32)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Exit: DeserializationContext::startElement()
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Enter: DeserializationContext::endElement(, name)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle) org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(popHandler00)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Popping handler org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHandler@16d22f1
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.utils.NSStack) NSPop (32)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Popped element stack to org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement:property
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Exit: DeserializationContext::endElement()
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Enter: DeserializationContext::startElement(, value)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle) org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(pushHandler00)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Pushing handler org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHandler@16880ba
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle) org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(newElem00)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement) New MessageElement (org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement@1db74af) named {}value
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Pushing element value
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.utils.NSStack) NSPush (32)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Exit: DeserializationContext::startElement()
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Enter: DeserializationContext::endElement(, value)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle) org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(popHandler00)
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext) Popping handler org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHandler@16880ba
DEBUG (org.apache.axis.utils.NSStack) NSPop (32)
```

I cannot use Axis2 because of technical reasons.

I have tried using HTTP Commons client instead of HTTP client but the response time remains the same.

How can i link a different parser(example xerces 2.10.0 or xstream 1.3.1?) to Axis 1.4 framework in this context so that memory management and response time is favorable?.

Answer (score 0):

From this link of [installation](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/install.html)
In the Axis directory, you will find a WEB-INF sub-directory. This directory contains some basic configuration information, but can also be used to contain the dependencies and web services you wish to deploy.

Axis needs to be able to find an XML parser. If your application server or Java runtime does not make one visible to web applications, you need to download and add it. Java 1.4 includes the Crimson parser, so you can omit this stage, though the Axis team prefer Xerces.

To add an XML parser, acquire the JAXP 1.1 XML compliant parser of your choice. We recommend Xerces jars from the xml-xerces distribution, though others mostly work. Unless your JRE or app server has its own specific requirements, you can add the parser's libraries to axis/WEB-INF/lib. The examples in this guide use Xerces. This guide adds xml-apis.jar and xercesImpl.jar to the AXISCLASSPATH so that Axis can find the parser (see below).

If you get ClassNotFound errors relating to Xerces or DOM then you do not have an XML parser installed, or your CLASSPATH (or AXISCLASSPATH) variables are not correctly configured.
In order for these examples to work, java must be able to find axis.jar, commons-discovery.jar, commons-logging.jar, jaxrpc.jar, saaj.jar, log4j-1.2.8.jar (or whatever is appropriate for your chosen logging implementation), and the XML parser jar file or files (e.g., xerces.jar). These examples do this by adding these files to AXISCLASSPATH and then specifying the AXISCLASSPATH when you run them. Also for these examples, we have copied the xml-apis.jar and xercesImpl.jar files into the AXIS_LIB directory. An alternative would be to add your XML parser's jar file directly to the AXISCLASSPATH variable or to add all these files to your CLASSPATH variable.

On Windows, this can be done via the following. For this document we assume that you have installed Axis in C:\axis. To store this information permanently in WinNT/2000/XP you will need to right click on "My Computer" and select "Properties". Click the "Advanced" tab and create the new environmental variables. It is often better to use WordPad to create the variable string and then paste it into the appropriate text field.

```
set AXIS_HOME=c:\axis
set AXIS_LIB=%AXIS_HOME%\lib
set AXISCLASSPATH=%AXIS_LIB%\axis.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\commons-discovery.jar;
  %AXIS_LIB%\commons-logging.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\jaxrpc.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\saaj.jar;
  %AXIS_LIB%\log4j-1.2.8.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\xml-apis.jar;%AXIS_LIB%\xercesImpl.jar;
  %AXIS_LIB%\wsdl4j.jar
```

Unix users have to do something similar. Below we have installed AXIS into /usr/axis and are using the bash shell. See your shell's documentation for differences. To make variables permanent you will need to add them to your shell's startup (dot) files. Again, see your shell's documentation.

```
set AXIS_HOME=/usr/axis
set AXIS_LIB=$AXIS_HOME/lib
set AXISCLASSPATH=$AXIS_LIB/axis.jar:$AXIS_LIB/commons-discovery.jar:
  $AXIS_LIB/commons-logging.jar:$AXIS_LIB/jaxrpc.jar:$AXIS_LIB/saaj.jar:
  $AXIS_LIB/log4j-1.2.8.jar:$AXIS_LIB/xml-apis.jar:$AXIS_LIB/xercesImpl.jar:
  $AXIS_LIB/wsdl4j.jar
export AXIS_HOME; export AXIS_LIB; export AXISCLASSPATH
```

To use Axis client code, you can select AXISCLASSPATH when invoking Java by entering

```
java -cp %AXISCLASSPATH% ...
```

Comment: Thanks . But due to critical nature, i had to use axis2 instead. axis2 was comparatively faster and less memory intensive.